# Use google cloud storage/bigdata as mysql database for php app

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

Is it possible to link one of the Google's service - cloud storage or bigdata with PHP  application - to act as a MySQL database?

My PHP application is handling too much data and there are time consuming queries behind.

It'd be great if I could use Google's database to speed up my queries.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Amazon's RDS sounds very much like what you'd want (I have no experience with it).

Answer (score 0):

Google app engine offers a MySql instance and has PHP support. The MySQL instance is not really a MySQL instance but a shared virtual database that might perform better than a single instance.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

To use Google specific storage layers (that will perform better) you can't use mysql directly. You could make a RPC from your PHP application to an app engine app that would just manage the datastore (e.g. insert, update, delete methods). That will require any PHP mysql statement to be re-written to a request to the app engine.